Pdf Preview Angular
I need to display a preview of a pdf file in the angular component, i tried to use pdfjs-dist lib, but i can't get an preview, also i tried ngx-extened-pdf-preview, but it`s looks like pdf-editor.
 <div class="pdf-body">
        <canvas id="pdf-preview-{{$index}}"></canvas>
        <p>{{ file.description }}</p>
 </div>

in pdf-body i tried to get a small picture of pdf, but i got nothing.
Maybe there are some new libs for this problem?
